# App redirects to Login Page after every Form Submit operation

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am writing an ASP.NET 8.0 Blazor Server App. I am using Microsoft Identity Framework Core for authorization. It loads menu items after successful user login only. I have used the following authorisation scenario on both `NavMenu.razor` and `Home.razor` components.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        ........
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Components.Account.Pages.Login>

        </Components.Account.Pages.Login>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

When app loads, it asks for login. At successful login, it displays the menu items in the `sidebar`. When I perform a submit operation on any of the pages, all the menu items disappear and it displays the login page again.

Here is my `program.cs` code:

```
using GetTutorsOnline.Components;
using GetTutorsOnline.Components.Account;
using GetTutorsOnline.Data;
using GTO.IModels.IModelRepos;
using GTO.Infrastructure.Data;
using GTO.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityCookies();

var conStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DifriPediaSQLDb");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<GTODbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conStr));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conStr));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<GTOAppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<GTOAppUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubjectNameRepo, SubjectNameRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegionRepo, RegionRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAssessmentMonthRepo, AssessmentMonthRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IELevelRepo, ELevelRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITeacherRepo, TeacherRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICoordinatorRepo, CoordinatorRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IManagerRepo, ManagerRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStudentRepo, StudentRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IParentRepo, ParentRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEvaluationTweekRepo, EvaluationTweekRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubjectAllocationRepo, SubjectAllocationRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDayNameRepo, DayNameRepo>();


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

//app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you post your middleware pipeline (`Configure` method, or your `Program` class)?

Comment: Yes, I have added 'program.cs' code to the main question